# Online games region restrictions

Tags: region-lock

Is it possible to buy games in Asia (from web or when on holiday) and then play them in Europe? I'm worried that they may be some region restrictions on them.

It's mostly games from US or European game publishers I'm worried about.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Steam limitations

On Steam you can "circumvent" store limitations through gifts. For example, if you live in Germany, you can still get Doom II from Steam if you get a friend in another country to gift (say, the USA) it to you. Alternatively, you can travel to where those games are available and buy them yourself. :)

I don't know, however, if this works for:

- games that are still available to you, but in different versions (say, the ["Low Violence Versions"](http://store.steampowered.com/app/550/?cc=de), which sometimes even only come with [mandatory dubbing](http://store.steampowered.com/app/7670/?cc=de)), and
- games that *will* be available to you but are currently locked in your region

Remeber that you can view a country's store by using the `cc` parameter. For example, compare [`http://store.steampowered.com/app/2300/?cc=it`](http://store.steampowered.com/app/2300/?cc=it) with [`http://store.steampowered.com/app/2300/?cc=de`](http://store.steampowered.com/app/2300/?cc=de).

Comment: Warning: all these links set a cookie that makes the country code "sticky" for your session. If you want to later see your country's Steam store from your browser, don't forget to clear the cookies!

Comment: ... or use your own country code for the `cc` parameter

Comment: «The problem with buying them yourself is that you need at least a payment method that is registered on the country you're in, i.e. if you're in the Netherlands, I think you either need a credit card or a Paypal account that is registered on the Netherlands» – [Cort](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/1268) (who I investigated this issue with)

Comment: if you contact Steam on the matter then you can use @alexanderpas's suggestion to buy games from your native country's store.  ie: I can use my american card to buy games while in Australia now (if it weren't for the fact that Visa thinks that I'm a scammer)

Comment: Just to clarify -- I wasn't replying to Alexander, I was replying to "Alternatively, you can travel to where those games are available and buy them yourself. :)"

Answer (score 1):

Usually what happens with these kinds of games, is that "Region-locked" doesn't refer to "can only play games when you're within country X" but rather "Your online play will always connect you to server 42, which is located in country X"

So if you buy Starcraft 2 in America, and decide to take it with you on a trip to Europe, you can still play Starcraft 2 just fine (assuming you have a powerful enough laptop), but any online multiplayer you were planning on doing is going to be routed to the N.A. server - which may mean horrendous lag on your end.

But the bottom line is, **it depends on the game**. Do your research before you buy. Did you have a specific game in mind?